# How to fix "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $jscomp" (phantomjs) or "ReferenceError: $jscomp is not defined" (firefox, chromium)?

Tags: angularjs, google-closure-compiler

After compiling javascript code with closure compiler (v20190729.0.0, previous versions too), I get `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $jscomp`.
Is there a solution that does not require to turn polyfills off with the option `--rewrite_polyfills=false`?

Comment: What settings are you using? Have you looked at "deps.js" https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/depswriter which is usually used to enable a "development mode" where the closure library isn't recompiled on each file change?

Comment: @GrahamPHeath, I use `--warning_level DEFAULT --jscomp_error checkVars --compilation_level SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS` and I compile without closure's base.js.

Comment: This happens in production mode where I do not use deps.js, while in development mode I provide deps.js, and polyfills (with $jscomp) are not introduced by the compiler because of `--compilation_level WHITESPACE_ONLY`,

Answer (score 1):

If I follow, it's a bit confusing which `compilation_level` you are using, based on your comments;

If you're using `WHITESPACE_ONLY` it might be that you're expecting Closure to do more than its doing (bundling). "The output JavaScript is functionally identical to the source JavaScript." so if you're adding deps.js in dev, and then compiling with closure, you'll still need deps.js.